# usermanager.addtorole - An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am adding a user to my aspnetusers database and that is working fine.  Then I am also trying to link them to an existing role.  That is when I get the error: "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending."

Here is my method with the problem code:

```
private async void checkOldDB(string email, string password)
    {
        bool isValidUser = false;
        ReportsMvc.App_Code.BLL.FUN.cFunUser user = ReportsMvc.App_Code.DAL.FUN.cFunUserDB.getUser(email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            isValidUser = PasswordHash.PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(password, user.Password);
            if (!isValidUser)
            {
                isValidUser = PasswordHash.PasswordHash.ValidateHashes(password, user.Password);
            }
        }

        if (isValidUser)
        {
            var user2 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = email, Email = email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user2, password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                string role = user.Role;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
                {
                    role = "User";
                }
                UserManager.AddToRole(user2.Id, role);
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user2, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);                        
            }
        }
    }
```

The line starting with "await SignInManager" was working fine.  Then when I added in that code to AddToRole, I started getting the above error.  This identity/authentication stuff is all very new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `async void` to `async Task` and `await` it where you call it.

As a general rule, you should avoid `async void`; it should only be used for event handlers. I describe this more in [an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).